# partial not discovered from identity area

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-7.0

Working on a `asp.net core` web app. I have moved a partial from the `/Views/Shared` folder to a subfolder `/Views/Shared/MenuPartials`.

The Identity has been completely scaffolded and is as code inside the project in `Areas/Identitys/Pages`. Currently only some extra fields added in `Manage/Index.cshtml` and the code behind.

In `Program.cs` I have added a ViewLocationFormat.

```
builder.Services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    // {2} area, {1} controller,{0} action - all actions in folder
    options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/Shared/MenuPartials/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
});
```

In my app this works well. However as soon as I go to the Identity pages at `https://localhost:44347/Identity/Account/Manage` , the new seach path is not honored, and I will get unhandled exceptions like this:

```
InvalidOperationException: The partial view '_admin' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/_admin.cshtml
/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/_admin.cshtml
/Areas/Identity/Pages/_admin.cshtml
/Areas/Identity/Pages/Shared/_admin.cshtml
/Areas/Identity/Views/Shared/_admin.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/_admin.cshtml
/Views/Shared/_admin.cshtml
```

Why is Identity not using the additional view discovery ? If I rename the `_admin.cshtml` and try from within my app (without area) I can see that the search path is working

```
InvalidOperationException: The partial view '_admin' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/_admin.cshtml
/Views/Shared/_admin.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/_admin.cshtml
/Views/Shared/MenuPartials/_admin.cshtml
/Views/Shared/ButtonPartials/_admin.cshtml
```

How can I make the Identity area to search in my `MenuPartials` and `ButtonPartials` ?

**EDIT:**
I did test adding this line as `Neil W` suggested in his answer.

```
options.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/Shared/MenuPartials/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
```

But it does not make any difference.
**/EDIT:**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching around got me to test some other functionalities. I added

```
options.AreaPageViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/Shared/MenuPartials/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
```

and the Identity area can find my _admin view. Probably Identities relies on `PageViewLocations` only.

The 'why' is not answered yet, but I guess it may have to do with `Blazor` vs `Razor` pages ?

Answer (score 0):

Configuring ViewLocationFormats for Areas is handled independently of the broader application.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorviewengineoptions.areaviewlocationformats?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Try:

```
options.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/Views/Shared/MenuPartials/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
```

Comment: I would swear I had tried this, and now I tried again. I still get the unhandled exception showing there's no `/Views/Shared/MenuPartials/_admin.cshtml` in the search locations. 

However, I have scaffolded the all identity pages for customization. Maybe that is causing a difference (I will updat this in my question)